# dynamic tbody scrolling without fixed height on tbody

Tags: html, css

i've been breaking my head over this issue.

I have a div layout where certain divs can be collapsed or shown. Below those divs is a div with a table in it. What i want is that the tbody becomes scrollable when the content no longer fits on the page. I can't give the tbody a fixed height (what i did do in the example to show the scroll i want). the table should adjust based on the available height and the tbody should become scrollable when it doesn't fit, to prevent page stretching.

I'm clueless...

https://jsfiddle.net/cr1bat27/3/

```js
function checkFilters(){
 var filters = document.getElementById("filterDiv");
  if(filters.style.display == "none"){
   filters.style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
   filters.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
}
#mainPage{
    height:100%;
}
#leftContainer{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height: CALC(100% - 50px);
}
#rightContainer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width:50%;
    height: CALC(100% - 50px);
    background-color: yellow;
}
#tabPanel {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 50px;
}
#filterDiv{
  height: 300px;
}
#filters{
  background-color:grey;
}
table{
   width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
td{
  height: 100px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
th{
  text-align: left;
}
#contentContainer{
  height: 100%;
}
tbody{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
}
thead tr{
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage">
  <div id="tabPanel">
  </div>
  <div id="leftContainer">
    <div id="contentContainer">
      <div id="filters">
        <div>
          <a onclick='checkFilters();'>Anchor - click me</a>
        </div>
        <div id="filterDiv">
          I SOMETIMES TAKE UP SPACE
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table container">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>stuff</th>
              <th>more</th>
              <th>stuff</th>
            </tr>  
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
              <td>info</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightContainer">
   IGNORE THIS RIGHT STUFF
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question looks like a high-quality question but can you state your clearly **as question**? E.g. "How can I ...?", "What I need to ..?"

Answer (score 0):

Use 'max-height' instead of 'height' in your css.

```
tbody{
  display:block;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: That won't solve the page stretching, which i want to avoid.